# Automatically authenticate a user in Moodle

Tags: php, api, authentication, moodle

I am trying to automatically authenticate a user in Moodle but having trouble using authenticate_user_login in Moodle 3.8.3.
I have tested the below code but I get the following error:

Exception - Argument 1 passed to core\session\manager::login_user() must be an instance of stdClass, boolean given, called in [dirroot]/lib/moodlelib.php on line 4632

Appreciate your help.

```
<?php
require('config.php');
$name="myusername";
$password="mypassword";
$dashboard = $CFG->wwwroot;
$user = authenticate_user_login($name, $password);
if(complete_user_login($user))
{
echo "login";
}
else
{
   echo "not login";
}



?>
```

Comment: Hi Matty,
When calling authenticate_user_login, what does it return?
check if you are getting an object or false. https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/MOODLE_38_STABLE/lib/moodlelib.php#L4384-L4407

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this message during Moodle SSO work if the `$password` value passed to `authenticate_user` does not match the user's actual password. In that case, `$user` returns false, which is then passed to `complete_user_login` and eventually to `login_user` , triggering the error. After updating the password to match, all worked as expected.

Guessing the same result would occur if `$name` does not exist or anything else that would return false from `authenticate_user_login`, although haven't had chance to test other scenarios.